# Какой формат даты в JSON?

Tags: json, datetime

Везде написано что YYYY-MM-DD но у меня Postman выдаёт ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format

Comment: Такой формат как указан там - не работает

Comment: Json не имеет нативного типа "дата". В документации к API должно быть написано, в каком формате ожидается дата. Она должна передаваться в виде строки и парситься на стороне сервера. "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z" - это стандартный [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) формат, должно канать везде.

Comment: Вы вообще вместо даты нарисовали арифметическое выражение с двумя вычитаниями.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Ваш развёрнутый комментарий помог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно стандарту https://www.json.org/json-en.html в json нет типа для даты.

По соглашению сторон дата должна быть или числом (например, unix-timestamp) или строкой в кавычках (например в формате ISO 8601)

На скриншоте пропущены кавычки.